# rlang and enquo does not work inside brackets

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I am trying to write a function that operates on a data.frame and will accept dplyr-style arguments, i.e. column names that are not quoted by using dplyr's pronous (or whatever we call it).

But I have encountered a problem when using `!!` inside a bracketed expression (see below the examples).

**Examples:**

First a data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(gah=c('a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'), 
                 fruit=c('apple','apple','apple','banana','banana','banana','dog','dog'),
                 val=1:8, 
                 sss=-7:0,
                 mean=0)
```

First function, it averages a fixed column (`val`) as well as a column as given by the argument. It does not modify the grouping:

```
a_func <- function(df, value=val) {
  value_ = enquo(value)
  df %>% summarise(mean=mean(!!value_), mean_val=mean(val), n=n())
}
a_func(df, sss)
df %>% group_by(gah) %>% a_func()
df %>% group_by(gah) %>% a_func(sss)
df %>% group_by(gah, fruit) %>% a_func
```

This works as expected.

The next function adds a grouping variable before using `summarise`:

```
c_func <- function(df, gr) {
  gr_ = enquo(gr)
  df %>% group_by(!!gr_) %>% summarise(n=n())
}
c_func(df, gah)
c_func(df, gr=gah)
c_func(df, fruit)
```

This also works as expected.

Next, I combine the two. That should be doable - and it in fact is! Praise the Holy Kitten!

```
b_func <- function(df, value=val, gr=NA) {
  value_ = enquo(value)
  gr_ = enquo(gr)
  df %>% group_by(!!gr_, add=TRUE) %>%
    summarise(mean=mean(!!value_), mean_val=mean(val))
}
b_func(df, sss)
df %>% group_by(gah) %>% b_func(gr=fruit)
b_func(df, gr=fruit)
df %>% group_by(gah) %>% b_func(sss, fruit)
```

It clearly works as expected, albeit, with the optional argument `gr` I would like to only add the grouping variable when `gr` is *not* `NA`.

**This is were it breaks:**
Adding a conditional to only do the grouping when `gr` is not `NA`, 
looking for the quosure from within the bracket somehow does not work.

```
d_func <- function(df, value=val, gr=NA) {
  value_ = enquo(value)
  gr_ = enquo(gr)
  if (!is.na(gr)) {
    df <- df %>% group_by(!!gr_)
  }
  df %>% 
    summarise(mean=mean(!!value_), mean_val=mean(val))
}
d_func(df, sss) # works
df %>% group_by(gah) %>% d_func(gr=fruit)
# Error in d_func(., gr = fruit) : object 'fruit' not found
d_func(df, gr=fruit) 
# Error in d_func(df, gr = fruit) : object 'fruit' not found
df %>% group_by(gah) %>% d_func(sss, fruit)
# Error in d_func(., sss, fruit) : object 'fruit' not found
```

It is clearly due to `!!gr_` being called within the scope of additional brackets; remove the if and it's brackets and `d_func` is equivalent to `b_func`, and both groups by a column `NA`.

I do not understand why this occurs or how to solve this.

**Updated with sessionInfo**

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rlang_0.2.0          bindrcpp_0.2.2       lemon_0.4.0          tidyr_0.8.0          magrittr_1.5        
[6] dplyr_0.7.4          odbc_1.1.5           RevoUtils_10.0.9     RevoUtilsMath_10.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16       pillar_1.2.1       compiler_3.4.4     plyr_1.8.4         bindr_0.1.1        tools_3.4.4       
 [7] bit_1.1-12         tibble_1.4.2       gtable_0.2.0       lattice_0.20-35    pkgconfig_2.0.1    openxlsx_4.0.17   
[13] cli_1.0.0          rstudioapi_0.7     DBI_0.8            yaml_2.1.18        gridExtra_2.3      knitr_1.20        
[19] hms_0.4.2          bit64_0.9-7        grid_3.4.4         tidyselect_0.2.4   glue_1.2.0         R6_2.2.2          
[25] ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 purrr_0.2.4        blob_1.1.1         scales_0.5.0       assertthat_0.2.0   colorspace_1.3-2  
[31] utf8_1.1.3         lazyeval_0.2.1     munsell_0.4.3      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: I get a warning instead of an error with the last set of code blocks.  The reason is due to `if (!is.na(gr))` where `if/else` works on a single element instead of a vector with length > 1.  Could be due to the versions for the error?

Comment: The warning should also go away with `if (!is.na(quo_name(gr_)))`

Comment: I've updated with sessionInfo. As far as I can see, `gr` can not be interpreted as a vector, so why should the if complain?

Comment: It is a quosure, so `length(quo(fruit))#
[1] 2`  and the reason is `as.character(quo(fruit))#
[1] "~"     "fruit"`
I am using `dplyr_0.7.5` with `rlang_0.2.1`

Comment: `df %>% group_by(gah) %>% d_func(gr=fruit) %>% dim#[1] 3 3` or `

`d_func(df, gr=fruit) %>% dim#[1] 3 3`

Comment: I see now. So just to be clear, is `gr` the quosure, or is `gr_` the quosure? But it appears that regardless, I can only interrogate and act on `gr_`, not `gr`?

Comment: I meant the `gr_` is a quosure and with `gr` if you use `print(gr)` within the function, it returns the vector of 'fruit'  column.  So, it is getting evaluated

Comment: Let me try on a fresh session in case there is a `fruit` object

Comment: I think `fruit` is a default vector dataset that gets in the way of evaluation, but anyway the function should work once `is.na` with `gr_` is fixed with the versions correct

Comment: Can't say about a default `fruit` vector, but I am clearly enlightned. Thanks for the help. Now I just need to solve how to evaluate whether the argument is missing, NA, or not.

Comment: in order to me to understand - you want the function to evaluate 'gr' as 'NA' when you specify the 'gr' argument, even if it is non-existent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a late answer, but the issue with your implementation of `d_func` is that you're mixing standard and non-standard evaluation of the same variable. You're using `enquo` to capture the expression given to `gr` in the calling environment (non-standard evaluation), while at the same time testing if the value held by the variable `gr` is `NA` (standard evaluation).

In case of standard evaluation (as in `!is.na(gr)`), `gr` will evaluate to the value held by the variable `fruit`, NOT the expression `fruit`. In your case, variable `fruit` was never defined. In akrun's case -- who likely did `library(tidyverse)` -- `fruit` evaluates to a pre-defined string vector that comes from `stringr::fruit` and contains various fruit names.

In either case, the behavior is not desirable. Your goal is to perform a specific action only if `gr` was specified. R provides a primitive function `missing()` that can be used for this purpose. If you replace

```
if (!is.na(gr)) {
```

with

```
if (!missing(gr)) {
```

all four of your test cases will work as expected.

Comment: That is a great and instructional answer. I can fully see where my fault is. And great on "debugging" akrun's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, @MrGumble. Happy to help.